# Redirect from www to non-www with exceptions

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, redirect

I want to create a rule using IIS URL-Rewrite module. I want to redirect all pages from www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com

However, there are some pages on teh site that I do not like to have redirection. Those pages are

1. www.mydomain.com/mail/default.asp
2. www.mydomain.com/mail2/default.aspx

So here is my code so far

```
                <rule name="Force non-WWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/mail/(.*)" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/mail2/(.*)" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

However, if I enable this rule and I go to www.mydomain.com/page, I got 500 error.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

Just add condition `<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/some-url/(.*)" negate="true" />`.You could use below rule:

```
 <rule name="Force non-WWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/mail/(.*)" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(www\.)(.*)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:2}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
```

Regards,
Jalpa.